# mysql statement using a for loop php

Tags: php

I have a mysql query which is being to find the stock items in a certain location belonging to a certain group. Hence this is going through 4 levels of `while loops`. No i have given the user the ability to select the locations they want to view the stocks from. This is being achieved using checkboxes which are sent using ajax in an array. The array `exploded in PHP` using `$offices = explode(",", $locations);`. However now i want to use the locations selected in my mysql query.

`$location` are in the form of  `location1, location2, location3, location4`

```
//selecting all locations using the statement below, however i want to select the locations that where selected by user.

$sql4 = mysql_query("select OfficeID, OfficeTitle from Office where 'wanted locations');
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4)) {
        $curr_location = $row3[0];

        $sql3 = mysql_query("select Quantity from Stock_Management where Book_ID = '$curr_book' and Location_ID = '$curr_location'");
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
            echo "<td>".$row3[0]."</td>";
        }   
    }
    echo "</tr>";
```

I want to select the locations based on the selected locations by user, now this can be achievable using a for loop by i don't know how to include that in my sql query!

Comment: and the question was what again ?

Comment: in the commented area of the code. I want to select the locations in that sql query based on the selected locations by user.

Comment: i'm a bit scared with this bunch of code :D

Comment: @PaulDinh Lol, just removed the extra bits that were not required.

Comment: @PaulDinh: will do that!

Comment: what these locations are? numbers? strings? what is the content of $locations?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, check updated question, they are strings

Comment: what if location contains a comma itself, like `Washington,DC`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, that has been taken care of while choosing the Location Title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$locations = mysql_real_escape_string($locations);
$locations = str_replace(",","','",$locations);

$sql = "select OfficeID, OfficeTitle from Office WHERE location in ('$locations')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$offices = explode(",", $locations);
$loc =  implode("','", $offices);
```

This helps is creating the variable `$loc` to `location1','location2',location3`

`$sql4 = mysql_query("select OfficeID, OfficeTitle from Office where OfficeTitle IN ('$loc')");`

This creates the mysql query to be:

`$sql4 = mysql_query("select OfficeID, OfficeTitle from Office where OfficeTitle IN ('location1','location2',location3')");`, which solves the purpose for now.

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT OfficeID, OfficeTitle FROM Office WHERE OfficeID IN ( $locations );`  ??

Also, look up `mysql_real_escape_string` and 'separation of concerns`

Comment: how mysql_real_escape_string can help here?

Comment: It won't help with your solution. But it helps protect your application. Don't write your queries without it.

Comment: how mysql_real_escape_string can help to protect this application?

Comment: "look it up" is not an answer. -1.

Comment: You're expected to do some research yourself instead of me explaining the concept of protecting queries to you.

Comment: Wow! You just took my answer and copied it as your own. That's real cheap.

Comment: yup. that's how I've got all my rep.